# batch file extract numbers from text file with little information

Tags: string, batch-file, extract

So This is related to my other two posts. Im dealing with extracting text from a text file and analyzing it and I've run into some problems. For A while I've been using a method that sets all the text between two other strings as a variable, but here is the situation I have. I need to extract the speed (numbers) from the below string: `"etc...,query":{"ping":47855},"cmts":...etc`. The problem is that the text `cmts` sometimes changes to something else so really I need to extract all the numbers from this:

```
,query":{"ping":47855},"
```

One more thing that makes this difficult is that the characters }," Are all over the file. Thank you for helping me! -Lucas EDG Programmer.
Here's the full file:

```
{"_id":53291,"ip":"158.69.22.95","domain":"jectile.com","port":25565,"url":"","date_add":1453897770,"status":1,"scan":1,"uptime":99.53,"last_update":1485436105,"geo":{"country":"US","country_name":"United States","city":"Lake Forest"},"info":{"name":" Jectile | jectile.com                        [1.8-1.11]\n Shoota (Call of Duty) \/ Zambies (Zombie Survival)","type":"FML","version":"1.10","plugins":[],"players":18,"max_players":420,"players_list":[],"map":"world","software":"BungeeCord 1.8.x, 1.9.x, 1.10.x, 1.11.x","avg_player_day":24.458333,"avg_load_day":5.8234,"platform":"MINECRAFT","icon":true},"counter":{"online":47871,"offline":228,"players":{"date":"2017-01-26","total":0},"last_offline":0,"query":{"ping":47855},"cmts":1},"rating":{"main":19.24,"difference":-0.64,"content_up":0.15,"K":0},"last":{"offline":1485415702,"online":1485436105},"chart":{"14:30":14,"14:40":16,"14:50":15,"15:00":18,"15:10":12,"15:20":13,"15:30":9,"15:40":9,"15:50":11,"16:00":12,"16:10":11,"16:20":11,"16:30":18,"16:40":25,"16:50":23,"17:00":27,"17:10":27,"17:20":23,"17:30":24,"17:40":26,"17:50":33,"18:00":31,"18:10":31,"18:20":32,"18:30":37,"18:40":38,"18:50":39,"19:00":38,"19:10":34,"19:20":33,"19:30":40,"19:40":36,"19:50":37,"20:00":38,"20:10":36,"20:20":38,"20:30":37,"20:40":37,"20:50":37,"21:00":34,"21:10":32,"21:20":33,"21:30":33,"21:40":29,"21:50":28,"22:00":26,"22:10":21,"22:20":24,"22:30":29,"22:40":22,"22:50":23,"23:00":27,"23:10":24,"23:20":26,"23:30":25,"23:40":28,"23:50":27,"00:00":32,"00:10":29,"00:20":33,"00:30":32,"00:40":31,"00:50":33,"01:00":40,"01:10":40,"01:20":40,"01:30":41,"01:40":45,"01:50":48,"02:00":43,"02:10":45,"02:20":46,"02:30":46,"02:40":43,"02:50":42,"03:00":39,"03:10":36,"03:20":44,"03:30":34,"03:40":0,"03:50":32,"04:00":35,"04:10":35,"04:20":33,"04:30":43,"04:40":37,"04:50":26,"05:00":31,"05:10":31,"05:20":27,"05:30":25,"05:40":26,"05:50":18,"06:00":13,"06:10":15,"06:20":17,"06:30":18,"06:40":17,"06:50":15,"07:00":16,"07:10":17,"07:20":16,"07:30":16,"07:40":18,"07:50":19,"08:00":14,"08:10":12,"08:20":12,"08:30":13,"08:40":17,"08:50":20,"09:00":18,"09:10":0,"09:20":0,"09:30":27,"09:40":18,"09:50":20,"10:00":15,"10:10":13,"10:20":12,"10:30":10,"10:40":10,"10:50":11,"11:00":13,"11:10":13,"11:20":16,"11:30":19,"11:40":17,"11:50":13,"12:00":10,"12:10":11,"12:20":12,"12:30":16,"12:40":15,"12:50":16,"13:00":14,"13:10":10,"13:20":13,"13:30":16,"13:40":16,"13:50":17,"14:00":20,"14:10":16,"14:20":16},"query":"ping","max_stat":{"max_online":{"date":1470764061,"players":129}},"status_query":"ok"}
```

By the way, the reason things change is because it looks at info from different servers

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you specifically have trouble with? What do you want to be extracted from your sample strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very similar to ther answer I gave you to your first question:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set/P var=<some.json
Set var=%var:*:{"ping":=%
Set var=%var:},=&:%
Echo=%var%
Timeout -1
```

Comment: I love you. (Not in that way)

Comment: By the way you can use pause instead of timeout -1, the timeout -1 command actually creates an error file deep inside task manager's log files, which if you use 1,000 times, amounts to a total storage usage of nothing. It really doesn't matter, but pause is what is designed for it. You know what, I'm not even going to post this because you probably know this.  EDIT: This made me laugh. I'll post it anyway.